# Keeping COM Interop in mind, are there any pitfalls in returning objects vs value types in .Net?

Tags: .net, c++, com

This question comes to mind when I consider using C++ to subscribe to a Library.  I don't have enough of an understanding of COM to make an educated guess at this point. But if I wanted to keep my code open for COM in the future (which is look more and more the case), I feel it would be safer to return value types than to return objects.  The downside is a would have to write a method/property for field item I want to expose.  Is this an unsubstantiated fear of mine?  If not, what do I need to consider to keeping my code COM frienldy in .Net when mingling with C++.  Thanks.

Comment: Both in COM and .NET it is safe to return an object.  COM because the client is using referencing counting so it is always the object owner that destroys it.  .NET because of the garbage collector.  It isn't safe to let native C++ object pass module boundaries unless you can provide hard guarantees about its layout, storage and lifetime management.

Comment: Set this to an answer, I would be inclined to accept given a reasonable amount time. :)